# ServiceStack WSDL does not include all types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wsdl, servicestack

I created a web service within my MVC application. All contracts are using the same namespace. `AssemblyInfo.cs` also maps the `ContractNameSpace` with `ClrNameSpace`.

The generated WSDL does not define my contract types.

This is my second project with ServiceStack. However, the results are different. 
Does contracts have to reside in a different assembly in order to ServiceStack to generate WSDL correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed in the latest ServiceStack release: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/306

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not using a dodgy tool like WCFStorm. I was getting the same issue even with the current ServiceStack release. I switched to soapUI and everything works expected.

Comment: I used both for testing, but i agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

The Types in the WSDLs and XSDs are determined by the Request + Response DTO's used in your services, i.e. they need to be used by your services to be included.

Also be sure to read through the [SOAP limitations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) to make sure there isn't anything you've missed.

If you still think it's an issue, submit an stand-alone project, via gist or pull-request that shows the issue.

Comment: I applied the guidelines including naming convention and assembly settings. however,the response type still not generated on XSDs Service Types.

on another project i use version 3.5.1 and it works perfectly. in the new project i use version 3.9.24. have Response type resolution changed?

Comment: Can you submit an empty stand-alone project via gist or pull-request that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: please find a sample project (MVC4 host) here https://www.dropbox.com/s/34mwe7g2k8atc15/MvcApplication1.rar

Comment: Can you add issues like these to the project issues site so it doesn't get lost, thx! https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues

Comment: sorry, I submitted the issue. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/306

Answer (score 0):

Your question is identical to the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609219/response-and-dto-objects-missing-from-xsd) I was having so I'll post my solution here:

I've downloaded the source code and done some investigation on my own. I'm not sure how recent this change is but it appears that in order for your DTO's and Response objects to be included in the wsdl you need to add a query string like "?includeAllTypes=true".

I'm also using the ServiceStack BasicAuthProvider setup which is causing AssignRoles and UnAssignRoles to be added to the Service automatically. The request and response objects for those calls are still failing to make it into the wsdl and causing "Add Service Reference" to fail. Fortunately we aren't making use of them so if I can find another configuration setting to remove them all should be working correctly.