# Response and DTO objects missing from XSD

Tags: soap, xsd, servicestack

I'm using the latest version of ServiceStack with NuGet. I've got a basic service setup that works fine with the JsonServiceClient and is passing all of our unit tests as expected.

Unfortunately I'm also trying to support SOAP and Visual Studios "Add Service Refernece" proxy generation for interop with other groups who want to continue using that sort of framework.

What I'm running into is that our DTO's including the Response objects are not being populated into the XSD's or wsdl's that ServiceStack is generating via the metadata page.  This seems very odd in conjunction with the fact that when viewing the individual SOAP Operation examples the correct Response and DTO's are shown in the generated example.

An Example Response:

```
Namespace Operations
    <DataContract>
    Public Class GetItemResponse
        Implements IHasResponseStatus

        <DataMember>
        Public Property ResponseStatus As ResponseStatus Implements IHasResponseStatus.ResponseStatus

        <DataMember>
        Public Property Item As Item
    End Class
End Namespace
```

An Example DTO:

```
Namespace Types
    <DataContract>
    Public Class Item
        <DataMember>
        Public Property ItemIdentifier As String
        <DataMember>
        Public Property ItemId As Guid?
        <DataMember>
        Public Property ItemName As String
        <DataMember>
        Public Property Description As String
        <DataMember>
        Public Property InstallDate As DateTime?
        <DataMember>
        Public Property FeatureNumber As String
        <DataMember>
        Public Property ModelNumber As String
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I'm using the Assembly: ContractNamespace attribute to set the XML namespace as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded the source code and done some investigation on my own.  I'm not sure how recent this change is but it appears that in order for your DTO's and Response objects to be included in the wsdl you need to add a query string like "?includeAllTypes=true".

I'm also using the ServiceStack BasicAuthProvider setup which is causing AssignRoles and UnAssignRoles to be added to the Service automatically.  The request and response objects for those calls are still failing to make it into the wsdl and causing "Add Service Reference" to fail. Fortunately we aren't making use of them so if I can find another configuration setting to remove them all should be working correctly.